# using drag-drop jquery ui with .append()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem when I use drag-drop ui and .append()

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showdata').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('showdata.php', function(data) {

            $('#show').append('<ul>'
                    + '<li><span class="droppable">'
                    + data['drop']+'</span></li>'
                    + '<li><span class="draggable">'
                    + data['drag']+'</span></li>'
                    + '</ul>');
        });

    });

    $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            alert($(this).attr('rel') + ' : ' + ui.draggable.text());

        }
    });

});
```

html:

```
<input type="button" id="showdata" value="Show Data" />
<div id="show">
    <ul>
        <li>Drop</li>
        <li>Drag</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

result: It's not working on drag and drop.

I don't know, maybe the problem comes from the .append().

for example: if I create directly html code

```
<input type="button" id="showdata" value="Show Data" />,
```

In javascript I can do:

```
$('#showdata').click(function(){ ... });
```

But, if I create it by using `.append()`
    .append(''),

I have to do:

```
$('#showdata').live('click', function(){ ... });
```

for clicking.

can anyone please help me?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you make something draggable or droppable, that only applies to what is currently on the page. Try making the elements draggable/droppable after each ajax call, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showdata').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('showdata.php', function(data) {

            var list = $('<ul></ul>');
            var li1 = $('<li><span>' + data['drop'] + '</span></li>');
            var li2 = $('<li><span>' + data['drag'] + '</span></li>');

            li2.draggable({
                revert: 'invalid'
            });

            li1.droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    alert($(this).attr('rel') + ' : ' + ui.draggable.text());
                }
            });

            list.append(li1).append(li2).appendTo('#show');

        });

    });

});
```